# How to configure Visual Studio Code on UBUNTU to compile gstreamer files

Tags: gcc, gstreamer

I have gstreamer and VSC installed on UBUNTU 18.04, and I can compile and run gstreamer tutorials from system command prompt by using instructions here: 
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c

Specifically, I can compile and run (The video pops up and plays):

`` gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 ``

I can even compile, but not run from the terminal/bash inside of VSC.

[image]

What I cannot do is compile or debug the code using the VSC IDE.  I have tried to configure the tasks.json file using the above suggested command from gstreamer tutorial like below.

[image]

When I try to run from the IDE by using ctr-f5, I get the below.

[image]

If I click show errors I get the below:

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Once I got smart enough to look at terminal to see what task was being executed from the tasks.json file, I figured out every item in the args array needs to be a separate item.

[image: VSC]

Then sweet gstreamer tutorials compile and run from VSC.

[image]

Also, if you want to use Code::Blocks one has to enter the `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` string into both compiler and linker "other command" areas in build options. Note there are back tics required in the above string that the stackoverlow editor has removed. See [gstreamer page](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c

For Ubuntu 16.04, follow https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/issues/4303

```
list=$(apt-cache --names-only search ^gstreamer1.0-* | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -v gstreamer1.0-hybris)
sudo apt-get install $list
```

For Ubuntu 16.04, you can also follow https://github.com/jackersson/env-setup/blob/master/gst-ubuntu-16-py/Dockerfile

Make sure
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! fakesink`
is working.

Here are the settings I used for building and debugging GStreamer in VS Code with IntelliSense on Ubuntu.

**.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json**

(got it from running `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-video-1.0 gtk+-3.0 gstreamer-1.0` in terminal for all libraries)

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/include/",
                "/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include",
                "/usr/include/gtk-3.0",
                "/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0",
                "/usr/include/at-spi-2.0",
                "/usr/include/dbus-1.0",
                "/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
                "/usr/include/harfbuzz",
                "/usr/include/atk-1.0",
                "/usr/include/pixman-1",
                "/usr/include/uuid",
                "/usr/include/freetype2",
                "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

**.vscode/tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "`",
                "pkg-config",
                "--cflags",
                "--libs",
                "gstreamer-1.0",
                "gstreamer-audio-1.0",
                "gstreamer-video-1.0",
                "gtk+-3.0",
                "gstreamer-pbutils-1.0",
                "`"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [
                "-e", "playbin", "uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

**.vscode/settings.json**

```
{
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 2, ColumnLimit: 0}",
    "files.associations": {
        "string": "c",
        "gst.h": "c",
        "gstdio.h": "c",
        "gprintf.h": "c",
        "gstbin.h": "c",
        "gstbuffer.h": "c",
        "gstbufferpool.h": "c"
    },
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled"
}
```

Bonus: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh